# Yii2 Form Fields

Tags: php, forms, field, yii2, crud

How can I edit the _search view (which is implemented by Yii2 Crud Generator), so that I can make two form fields on the same line?
(Note that I have resized the form fields to 500px so that they can fit one line).
Also, I would like the 'Search' and 'Reset' buttons to be on the same line too.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use options and assign eg: a proper twitter-bootstrap grid width

this way :

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'your_filed', ['options' => ['class' => 'col-md-4', ]]) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks again :D
 I used it and it worked but if it could work, i need search and reset buttons on the same line as the fields, and 'create car' on another line. @scaisEdge

Comment: I see the layout. you must insert a div for break after the two field or enlarge the width of the field eg: md-6 for  a better display

Comment: I really appreciate everything man :) But what should I do to make the buttons on the same level as the fields , and not the fields' labels?
@scaisEdge

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that the earch and reset buttons are placed in `<div class = 'form-group'>`. The form-group can take off without problems is just a way to format the page and at this point you can line up the buttons with the fields where such use col-md-1, or if the sum of the field  `col`  not ecced 12

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm gonna try to find a solution for this myself.. Regards